# How to loop trough dictionary and check if the ReadLine input is equal to the Dictionary Key

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Library> lib in dictionary)
            {
                if (userInput == lib.Key)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose book = {0}",lib.Value.bookName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
                }
            }
```

Hello i am stuck at figuring out how i can check equality userInput(ReadLine) to a Key in Dictionary without else command spamming "Wrong Input" while looping trough Dictionary.

Comment: just use public bool ContainsKey (TKey key); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.8 No foreach (or other loop) needed

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a method ContainsKey in the .Net lib.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.8

You can simply call this and removed the whole loop.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the Linq implementation by Nasar, you could use the `TryGetValue` method on dictionary ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8)).

The good thing about using `TryGetValue` is you only iterate the dictionary once to do 2 things.

1. Check if the value exists
2. Get the value from the dictionary

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (dictionary.TryGetValue(userInput, out Library library))
    Console.WriteLine($"You chose book = {library.bookName}");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
```

`TryGetValue` will return true if the record is found and false otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer aprreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Try a boolean to verify

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool exists= false;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Library> lib in dictionary)
            {
                if (userInput == lib.Key)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose book = {0}",lib.Value.bookName);
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if(!exists){
                  Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is essentially saying "for each key in the dictionary that is not equal to the one the user has entered then print wrong input.." which is clearly not what you want.

instead you want something along the lines of:

"iterate through the entire dictionary and if every single key is not equal to the one the user has entered then print wrong input..."

in order to achieve that:

1. you don't need an `else` block within the loop.
2. use a simple boolean variable that will tell you whether a match has been found or not during the iteration and then after the loop check the state of the boolean and then print "wrong input" if necessary.

Example:

```
bool wrongInput = true;
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,Library> lib in dictionary)
{
     if (userInput == lib.Key)
     {
           Console.WriteLine($"You chose book = {lib.Value.bookName}");
           wrongInput = false;
           break; // exit early as there's no need to continue the iterating.
     }
}

if (wrongInput) Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
```

---

Note that I've corrected your code for completeness but I would not recommend following the above approach i.e. iterating over a dictionary, instead look into `ContainsKey` instead of looping over the dictionary.... as it's the idiomatic, less code, more readable etc...

Comment: "Ultimately, look into ContainsKey instead of looping over the dictionary...." seems like we where thinking the same thing ;-)

Comment: @zilleplus seems like it indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your time and those were great answers but i am interested how i can then loop trough dictionary while using ContainsKey to display bookName

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize LinQ for this and shorten the code making it simple and easy to read. is would spend more time trying to validate the input from the user and make sure that the imputed value is a digit and nothing else.

```
 int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    var result = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == userInput);
    if(result.Value != null)
        Console.WriteLine("You chose book = {0}", result.Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
```

An alternative way would also to run a Boolean expression validating if the key exist before executing the fetch value.

```
        int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var result = dictionary.ContainsKey(userInput);

        if(!result)
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input");
        else
        {
            var book = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("You chose book = {0}", book.Value);
        }
```

Comment: `result` would be `null`, not just `result.Value` so this could cause a Null Ref exception :)

Comment: I ran the code before posting and no Null Ref exception was thrown. an object is created where the value is null.

Comment: But I do agree that its a risky approach to solving the problem.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`, which is a struct, so the default will never be `null`. But yeah, the `ContainsKey` way is much better. And if you want the value, too, `TryGetValue` would be even better.

Comment: I just tested and totally agree with both Corak and Matt that TryGetValue is a great approach the code gets pretty slim.